# How to explicitly fail cordova/ionic build if a plugin couldnot be installed?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have a very important plugin required by my app. In the build server, while adding platform or building using cordova cli , cordova tries to fetch a plugin. When plugin fetch is unsuccessfull, it silently shows error but the cordova build is still successfull. 
Ideally the build should fail if it cant fetch that plugin.

**How can I explicity fail the cordova build in that case so that I wont ship the unwanted build to device?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `cordova`, `npm`, `gradle` and `Apple LLVM` parts are not that tightly related. Each of them lives in their own ecosystem. That's why it can fail, yet succeed at the same time. Cordova doesn't really. care about npm, neither does either native compiler.

Notice how I, somewhat smugly, mentioned the native side? That's key. What you could do is create your own plugin that causes the native build to fail if certain files aren't present.

It doesn't have to be an official "plugin", just create a few files, include it in your config.xml as such:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-validator" spec="file:plugins/cordova-plugin-validator">
```

A pretty straightforward guide is available on their official website: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

You don't even need to create your validator plugin javascript file, you just need to include the native parts, something like (copied and modified from the guide, just change the file names):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="cordova-plugin-device" version="0.2.3">
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Device">
                <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <header-file src="src/ios/ImportantPluginValidator.h" />
        <source-file src="src/ios/ImportantPluginValidator.m" />
    </platform>
    platform name="android">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Validator">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.cordova.important.plugin.validator.ImportantPluginValidator"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/ImportantPluginValidator.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/plugin" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

And your iOS (.h and .m) and Android (.java) files just need to include your plugin packages, e.g.

```
import my.important.plugin;
```

and

```
#import "MyImportantPlugin.h"
```

And that's it. If those files and packages available, you're golden. If they are missing, the native compiler will fail with a hard **NOPE!**.

Comment: I am not sure if its a good solution to include a plugin whose purpose is just to fail the build process . I thought there would be some way to fail explicitly